# CSV file editing using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to do below using PowerShell scripting.

I have the below data in CSV file. I need to append another prefix to the name according to the subject supplied

```
Name,Subject,Roll,Div
Mark,Agri,3,Div1,
Tom,CS,6,Div3,
Alex,Aero,9,Div6
```

Suppose i am supplied the subject as `Agri`, the name should have prefix as `P-`. So the same CSV file will be saved and have below content

```
Name,Subject,Roll,Div
P-Mark,Agri,3,Div1,
Tom,CS,6,Div3,
Alex,Aero,9,Div6
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
(Import-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ',') | ForEach-Object{

    if($_.Subject -match "Agri" )
    {
      $_ = "P-" + "$_";

    }
    else
    {
     $_ = "F-" + "$_";

    }

} | Export-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ','
```

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to pipe this together - might just be ignorance on my part about powershell syntax. I was able to do it with the following using two lines:

```
($csv = Import-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ',') | ForEach {
    if ($_.Subject -match "Agri") {
        $_.Name = 'P-' + $_.Name
    } else {
        $_.Name = 'F-' + $_.Name
    }

}
$csv | Export-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoType
```

Notice:

```
$_ = "P-" + $_;
```

Becomes

```
$_.Name = "P-" + $_.Name;
```

Comment: I am getting blank file as out put. I need the same file to be modified as out put. Am I missing something?

Comment: Let me try testing it with files. I tested it keeping everything in powershell and using `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Comment: I'm having trouble piping this all into a single line. If I store the `$csv` into a variable first, and then do `$csv | Export-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ','` then it works fine...

Comment: Updated with two line answer

Comment: This deletes what's on the file when exported.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the use of paren's in the following clause.

```
($csv = Import-Csv E:\Test.csv -Delimiter ',')
```

will assign to `$csv` the output of `Import-Csv` PRIOR to the ForEach processing and therefore the ForEach effects are completely lost.  Not sure
what you purpose is in using those paren's.